# How to maintain session during embedded Docusign signing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi

I am trying to set up the ping_url in the docusign_esign gem to send ping requests to a specific endpoint in my Rails application while clients have redirected from my site to docusign to sign documents. The requests are not sending any cookies to my site though, and so I am unable to maintain the session.

Without control/ownership of the Javascript that is sending the Ajax request, I am unable to add them to the request. The docusign Documentation also explains that the response to the GET request is ignored.

I'm using cookies for session storage, so my initial thought was that the only way for me to maintain session is if I can get docusign to send the correct cookies.

This doesn't appear to be the designed flow though so I'm wondering:

1. What is the intended means of authentication behind the pingUrl?
2. And based on your first response, could you clarify what you mean by the returnUrl being “an intermediate simple web page”?

Additionally, I’m confused how this will help me maintain a session that is stored via cookies throughout the signing process which I expect will take longer (~10-15 minutes) than the duration of a user session (5 minutes). I'll try to clarify how I see the flow and maybe you can point out where I'm mistaken or what I'm missing.

Suppose my application browser, call it A, opens up a new tab for the docusign signing ceremony, call this browser D, and let’s call my server S.  Ultimately, I need to get D to communicate either to A or to S that the user is actively going through a document.  I first thought I’d try to use the pingUrl for this purpose, but D can’t send cookies to S.  At the same time, A can only passively receive communication from D, but I don’t understand how this should be listening to D which I have no control of.  I’m guessing the simple javascript web page you mentioned is intended to facilitate this, but I don’t understand how it fits in.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the cookies are not sent since that'd be cross-domain cookies.
Perhaps easier would be to open a new browser tab for the DocuSign signing ceremony rather than a redirect.

For example:
instead of the referer header, use Window.postMessage to communicate between a new browser tab and the parent browser tab that your application uses. This flow is demonstrated by the new [DocuSign React code example](https://www.docusign.com/blog/building-react-app-part-1-introduction)

1. When your application starts, it uses window.addEventListener to listen for messages. Here’s a [code example](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-react/blob/master/src/App.js#L74).
2. Later, your application creates a new browser tab and saves the resulting window object in a variable. The initial web page URL is the URL for the embedded DocuSign signing ceremony. The [returnUrl](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/#definition__recipientviewrequest_returnurl) is not your application’s URL. Instead, it is an intermediate simple web page with a JavaScript program.

That JavaScript program calls Window.postMessage to send the query parameters (from the embedded signing ceremony) to the parent page (your application). Here’s a code example of an intermediate page.

To send the query parameters, use window.location.search instead of the example’s window.location.hash.

3. When the message is sent, your web page’s listener method receives and processes the message. Eventually it closes the tab that it had opened in step 2 by using the Window.close method on the child tab’s window object saved in step 2.

Comment: I think I'm confused about two things still.  1. Even if I create a new tab for the signing ceremony, won't I still need to get state indicating that a user is active within the ceremony (which Docusign has full control of) to the client's browser of my own application (the parent application) so that it can refresh session with my server? 2. Could you explain what you mean by the return url being "an intermediate simple web page"? Is this URL not supposed to have the same domain as my webapp?  And how does the ping_url fit into this flow? Thanks!

Comment: To follow up on my first point of confusion, I'm not sure how window.postMessage helps me when the browser I want to be sending messages _from_ is the signing ceremony on the docusign site which I have no control over

Comment: You can have DocuSign redirect to a page in your domain (origin). That page uses the postMessage. See my [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/new-browser-security-settings-and-iframes). Re keeping your session alive. Your app is still running in your app's tab in the browser. So your app's web page can ping your server-backend. Re ping_url: not used in this pattern